# Is there any way to get pc name (hostname) in php on linux server hosting shell_exec function is not working

Tags: php, jquery, linux, server, hostname

Is there any way to get the PC name (hostname) in PHP on Linux server hosting? The `shell_exec` function is not working.

I am using this code:

```
$a = shell_exec('ipconfig/all');      
echo $a;
```

Comment: To be clear, the name of the **server** machine, or the name of the **client** machine viewing the site through the browser? The only reason I ask is because you've tagged this question with jQuery - which implies client-side logic

Comment: i am talking about client machine

Comment: the visitors ip?

Comment: That's not possible then.

Comment: in any another technologies ??

Comment: Yes, lots that execute directly on the client PC. Over the web? No.

Comment: apparently its possible using ActiveX, but that means IE only, and IE isn't even a browser, its a browser selection and download tool lmao. anyway here it is if you are interested https://programming.vip/docs/three-methods-for-js-to-obtain-client-ip-address-mac-and-host-name.html